# What is a proper way to disable captcha in Auth0 when run tests with Cypress

Tags: cypress, recaptcha, captcha, auth0

there is an app with Auth0 authentication. I am working on Cypress test suite. Today, after many test runs locally, Auth0 started to show captcha on a login page. This is something that is hard to automate and I don't want to do this.

Is there any way to disable captcha in Auth0 for Cypress tests? Are there any workarounds for this? I found a few articles how to generate authentication token with api call, but I personally don't support this. This is e2e testing and we should work with an app like with a black box.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can disable the captcha completely for an environment or maybe have it disabled for a dedicated automation user on the app.

Answer (score -1):

If You getting re like this,

[image]

You can try with,

```
/**
 * This method use to submit the the reCaptcha. 
 */
Cypress.Commands.add ("authenticateWithReCaptcha",()=>{

        cy.window().then(currentWindow => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(currentWindow.location.search);
            if (params.has("reCaptcha") &&
                currentWindow.document
                    .querySelector("iframe[src*='recaptcha']") &&
                getComputedStyle(currentWindow.document
                    .querySelector("iframe[src*='recaptcha']")).visibility === "visible") {
                        cy.window().invoke("submitForm");
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I've just read the code and couldn't catch what it is doing. It doesn't do a thing with reCAPTCHA but submit a form. If you submit a form with not solved captcha, there will be an error.